# Is there a way to reuse an XML declaration of a UI component in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've done some snooping around for what I feel is relatively simple, however, I guess I wasn't quite sure how to phrase this question because I wasn't getting many results. I apologize if this is a duplicate question. What I want to do is define an `EditText` with some attributes like so:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:digits="0123456789.,"
    android:ellipsize="start"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="    "/>
```

And from there, I wish to simply declare `MyEditText` (Assuming my above definition is called MyEditText), and not have to worry about defining these 9 attributes every time I wish to use an `EditText` of this style. Is this possible? I have read through [Android's guide to Custom components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html), however, it seems to be overkill for what I am trying to accomplish. (I do not wish to do anything custom persay, I'm just looking to package some already existing functionality into a single component.) Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the style for this.
You can create a style as-

```
   <style name="editText">
        <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/text_box_width</item>
        <item name="android:maxLines">2</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">40dp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">left</item>
    </style>
```

And you can set this style in the layout file as

```
<EditText 
 style="@style/editText" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Google ViewStub and see if that will work for your needs.

or I believe you could inflate a new `View` from the same `XML`:

```
 EditText anotherOne = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.yourLayoutXmlNameHere, null);
```